# how to insert data into many to many association sails js?

Tags: sails.js

I am new to sails js, and I want to insert data into mongodb using many to many association  , but I don't know which collection should I insert first and how to insert it. Below is my model:

```
// User.js
module.exports={
    attributes:{
        firstname:{
            type:'string'
        },
        lastname:{
            type:'string'
        },
        pets:{
            collection:'pet',
            via:'owners',
            dominant: true
        }
    }
};
```

---

```
// Pet.js
module.exports={
    attributes:{
        name:{
            type:'string'
        },
        type:{
            type:'string'
        },
        owners:{
            collection:'user',
            via:'pets'
        }
    }
};
```

I tried to insert data into pet collection first , but I didn't see the collection is updated. This is how I insert data into pet collection:

```
Pet.create({'name':req.body.name,'type':req.body.type}).exec(function(err,data){
  if(err) return next(err);
  res.json(data);
});
```

Thank in advance for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have existing User records, you can specify an array of them when adding your pet:

```
Pet.create({
  'name':req.body.name,
  'type':req.body.type, 
  'owners': [userId1, userId2]
}).exec(function(err,data){
  if(err) { return next(err); ]
  res.json(data);
});
```

Or, you can specify the new Pet's ID when adding a new User:

```
Pet.create({
  'name':req.body.name,
  'type':req.body.type
}).exec(function(err,newPet){
  if(err) { return next(err); ]
  User.create({ name: 'tom', pets: [newPet.id] }).exec(function(err, newUser) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    return res.json({ pet: newPet, user: newUser });
  });
});
```

After that, in Sails 0.12.x, you can add/remove items from the collection using the methods documented in [the associations docs](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/many-to-many).  In Sails 1.0, you'd use the [addToCollection](http://next.sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/add-to-collection), [removeFromCollection](http://next.sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/add-to-collection) and [replaceCollection](http://next.sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/replace-collection) methods.

Comment: I tried with the second choice , it does work, let's me try with the first choice!! Thank you!